# why "unknown amount"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I received "unknown amount" in 22 days ago, and my monero_gui showed it up until yesterday. Can anyone tell me the reason why and how about "unknown amount"?

Transaction ID: e0ca088610d7e94099ac970847faf9e141f7beffe33cfcc30b9fccccfe73d0fa

I am new to cryptcoin field. Thanks in advance

Lynx

Answer (score 1):

That is the feature of monero transactions, called confidential transactions (the CT in RingCT). Noone except receiver or sender can see transaction amount. You can see the amount only if you have right private view key. Also, due to zero-knowledge proofs system you still can verify that right amount of coins were deposited to the right address, even though you don't know who received or how much.